# want the link to take me to previous page and close current tab. (html , locally)

Tags: html

I have created a sign-up page, as practice, locally.
I have an anchor that takes me to the 'privacy policy' page.
This page is loaded on a new tab. Here, I have an anchor that takes me back to the sign-up page, by loading it again on the new tab.

I want to make it so that when the link is clicked, it returns to the original sign-up page and closes the new tab.

It doesn't have to be via the anchor method, but I prefer to have that if possible.

note - beginner.
what to do??

I tried using Anchor, but it loads upon the same tab.
I expect the current tab to close and return to the original tab.
I don't have the know-how to achieve this.

Comment: You can try to just call window.close(), but it may not work. There is really nothing you can do in HTML for this.

Answer (score -1):

There is no solution with HTML itself, instead you have to use javascript to handle this problem.

Follow these steps to solve this problem:

1. You need to Open the current page in the same tab using window.open() method
2. Close this newly opened tab

we do this because window.close() method only works with page opened with windows.open()

```
window.open("", "_self");
window.close();
```

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Browsers have closed the `window.open("", "_self");` loophole that used to trick them into thinking that a regular window was opened from a script.

Comment: Thanks. I got the answers from Javascript. But was wondering would just html can do it